# Can’t search in Windows 8 CP start menu

Tags: search, windows-8-preview

When I open the Start menu and type, search is not working. If I press <kbd>Win+Q</kbd> and type, search is not working. I also tried <kbd>Win+F</kbd> to no avail.

I can’t even find the indexing options to check my index locations. The main problem is with search in the Metro start menu.

On the same computer, this function worked in the developer preview version.

Comment: Did you upgrade or do a fresh install? In the first case you might want to do a fresh reinstall.

Comment: I did upgrade. And i dont want fresh install for now.. I thought that such things like search are not THAT system integrated. Its just another application with its index database, thats all...

Comment: I guess it takes the Windows Search database from your previous installation and continues on that, and if that's somehow broken then you have a problem. Try resetting the Windows Search Index.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. But how do i reset it? Cant even find Indexing Options(No such item in classic Control Panel)

Comment: Use the "to rebuild the index" link on http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Change-advanced-indexing-options

Comment: ".. then clicking Control Panel. In the search box, type indexing options, and then click Indexing Options." sorry, cant provide screenshot, but there is NO Indexing Options there.

Comment: Can i do that from cmd?

Comment: I have no idea, but I know that the options are supposed to be there... :S

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have turned on Windows Search service and that helped. I don't know why, but it wasn't enabled in my case.
See
https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/why-is-desktop-search-service-unavailable-308f0023-2052-4c80-959a-1530fef09b6c

Answer (score 1):

The Developer Preview is substantially different to the Consumer Preview. Shortcuts, programs and concepts from one do not necessarily transfer to the other.

The Indexing service options are still available in the legacy Control Panel which can be accessed via the Metro control panel.

Comment: Looked carefully in Control Panel. There is no Indexing Options. Anyway new start menu is really not useful without such indexed search(in my case).

Comment: You should look for the Indexing Options in the normal Control Panel, not in the Metro Control Panel. The Metro Control panel mostly only applies to the Metro part of Windows 8, while all the rest can be found in the normal Control Panel.

Comment: Sure ive looked in normal one. Cant provide the screenshot now, because im at work.